# How to co-group 5 RDDs or More

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

How to Cogroup 5 RDDs

```
JavaPairRDD<String ,ontologies1> ontologiesPair 
JavaPairRDD<String ,Instagram>  inpair
JavaPairRDD<String, Pinterest> pintpair
JavaPairRDD<String, Twitter> tweetpair
JavaPairRDD<String, Klout> kloutpair
```

I need to cogroup something like

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple5<Iterable<ontologies1>, Iterable<Instagram>, Iterable<Pinterest> ,Iterable<Klout>,Iterable<Twitter>>> comb1 =   ontologiesPair.cogroup(inpair,pintpair,kloutpair,tweetpair);
```

How Do I achieve this.